# Google Postmaster: IP reputation of subdomain and main domain identical

Tags: email, email-server, spam, g-suite, google

We have a main domain, example.com. We use this to send regular emails via Google GSuite.

We also have a subdomain, say sub1.example.com. We use this to send campaign emails through an email marketing service (Zoho Campaigns).

I would expect the IP reputation of example.com to be based on Google's mail servers.

However, both the IP reputations of example.com and sub1.example.com are exactly identical. In the IP details it only shows the IP addresses of Zoho Campaigns (according to https://ipinfo.io/)

Why is that so?